# How to move the last letter of a string to the front?

Tags: python, string

I'm doing the challenge in groklearning but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

My program needs to do a few things:

1. Check if word ends in ay, if it does:
2. Remove the ay from the end of the word
3. Move the (now) last letter to the front of the word.
4. Print out the new word.

I don't know how to move the letter to the front. This is my code so far:

```
word = input('Word: ') 
if 'ay' in word:
  word1 = word[-1] + word[:-1]
  word2 = word1[2:]
  word3 = word2[-1] + word2[:-1] 
  print(word3)
else:
  print(word)
```

If I were to type in 'athsmay' for the input, it sends out 'athsm'. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're already moving the last letter to the front just fine! Twice, for some reason. And chopping off the first two letters instead of the last two.

Comment: shouldn't your send out be `maths` for input `athsmay`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly test that the word ends with `'ay'`, and do the concatenation in one line:

```
>>> def rearrange(word):
...     if word.endswith('ay'):
...         word = word[-3] + word[:-3]
...     return word
... 
>>> rearrange('athsmay')
'maths'
```

Based on the rules you gave:

- Pop off 'ay' from the end, giving 'athsm'
- Move the last letter of that result to the front

`word[-3]` uses negative indexing, where `word[-1]` is the last letter in the word.  `word[:-3]` is the slice up to but not including that letter.

Comment: This was the solution, thank you!